# Current zone configuration for a DNS entry

Tags: domain-name-system

I just recently stepped into a new job out of college and am learning the ropes quickly. I have just been requested to move DNS for a specific domain name. The new clients asked for the current zone configuration of the DNS entry. Is this asking for the IP address of the host server? Or am I missing something bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are looking for more than just a single entry for your server, they are asking for the complete `zone` for your domain name.

The Zone consists of the `SOA` (Start Of Authority) record, and any `A`, `AAAA`, `CNAME`, `MX`, `PTR`, `SRV` and `TXT` records contained within that zone.

See wikipedia's entries for [Zone file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) and [DNS zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone) for a good overview of what you are looking for.

Comment: Why would a client who is taking over the Domain name need to know this information?

Comment: Most likely they want to pass this on to a new / different DNS Hosting company so that the existing zone is already in-place when they switch to the new host - essentially preventing downtime.  Once switched over, they would then make any required changes (ie, change the IP Address for certain `A` records, or redirect elsewhere by changing `A` records to `CNAME` records).  Of course, it's also possible that they have asked for the `zone`, which is as described above, but mean something different - it may be best to ask them what they expect to receive from you.

Answer (score 0):

They're looking for the list of records that configures the DNS server software with what entries that it needs to serve for a given domain - the "zone file", in DNS terminology.

What DNS software is it hosted on?  We can probably give more specific assistance with that information.